# Spring boot + Spring LDAP + Service Account + Bad Credentials

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-ldap

i am getting bad credentials exception when using active directory service account and the same code is  working fine for user account.

And there is nothing wrong with service user credentials.

Please find my code below.

```
@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
                "abc.def.ghi", "ldap://abc.def.ghi:389");
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The userPrincipleName property is not inline with expected format username@domainname for that specific user account.